# Parallel for each or any alternative for parallel loop?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, parallel.foreach

I have this code:

```
Lines.ToList().ForEach(y =>
{
    globalQueue.AddRange(GetTasks(y.LineCode).ToList());
});
```

So for each line in my list of lines I get the tasks that I add to a global production queue. I can have 8 lines. Each get task request `GetTasks(y.LineCode)` take 1 minute. I would like to use parallelism to be sure I request my 8 calls together and not one by one.

What should I do?

Using another `ForEach` loop or using another extension method? Is there a `ForEachAsync`? Make the `GetTasks` request itself `async`?

Comment: Is `GetTasks` `async`?

Comment: To expand on Liams comment (I assume!), if GetTasks is async you really wouldnt need to run the loop in parallel because the time it takes to start the task is usually insignificant.

Comment: @Liam No, not yet.

Comment: `Parallel.` methods are meant for CPU-bound data parallelism, not executing tasks concurrently. They're *definitely* not meant to modify global state. How many lines are there and what does `GetTasks()` do? It matters. If it performs IO you'll block your CPU doing nothing but wait for the IO to finish. In any case, if you want to produce results you can use PLINQ and consume the results *outside* `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: What is `globalQueue` and who listens to it? If you use channels or dataflows you can have N producers posting to 1 or more consumers instead of waiting to read from a global queue after processing completes

Comment: GetTasks return list of objects. globalQueue is a global list of objects that consolidate all.

Answer (score 2):

Parallelism isn't concurrency. Concurrency isn't asynchrony. Running multiple slow queries in parallel won't make them run faster, quite the opposite. These are different problems and require very different solutions. Without a specific problem one can only give generic advice.

**Parallelism - processing an 800K item array**

Parallelism means processing a ton of data using multiple cores in parallel. To do that, you need to partition your data and feed each partition to a "worker" for processing. You need to minimize communication between workers and the need of synchronization to get the best performance, otherwise your workers will spend CPU time doing nothing. That means, no global queue updating.

If you have a lot of lines, or if line processing is CPU-bound, you can use PLINQ to process it :

```
var query = from y in lines.AsParallel()
            from t in GetTasks(y.LineCode)
            select t;

var theResults=query.ToList();
```

That's it. No need to synchronize access to a queue, either through locking or using a concurrent collection. This will use all available cores though. You can add `WithDegreeOfParallelism()` to reduce the number of cores used to avoid freezing

**Concurrency - calling 2000 servers**

*Concurrency* on the other hand means doing several different things at the same time. No partitioning is involved.

For example, if I had to query 8 or 2000 servers for monitoring data (true story) I wouldn't use `Parallel` or PLINQ. For one thing, `Parallel` and PLINQ use all available cores. In this case though they won't be doing anything, they'll just wait for responses. Parallelism classes can't handle async methods either because there's no point - they aren't meant to *wait* for responses.

A very quick & dirty solution would be to start multiple tasks and wait for them to return, eg :

```
var tasks=lines.Select(y=>Task.Run(()=>GetTasks(y.LineCode));
//Array of individual results
var resultsArray=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

//flatten the results
var resultList=resultsArray.SelectMany(r=>r).ToList();
```

This will start all requests at once. Network Security didn't like the 2000 concurrent requests, since it looked like a hack attack and caused a bit of network flooding.

**Concurrency with Dataflow**

We can use the TPL Dataflow library and eg ActionBlock or TransformBlock to make the requests with a controlled degree of parallelism :

```
var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 ,
                    BoundedCapacity=10,
            };
var spamBlock=new TransformManyBlock<Line,Result>(
                               y=>GetTasks(y.LineCode),
                               options);
var outputBlock=new BufferBlock<Result>();
spamBlock.LinkTo(outputBlock);

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    await spamBlock.SendAsync(line);
}
spamBlock.Complete();
//Wait for all 4 workers to finish
await spamBlock.Completion;
```

Once the `spamBlock` completes, the results can be found in `outputBlock`. By setting a `BoundedCapacity` I ensure that the posting loop will wait if there are too many unprocessed messages in `spamBlock`'s input queue.

An `ActionBlock` can handle asynchronous methods too. Assuming `GetTasksAsync` returns a `Task<Result[]>` we can use:

```
var spamBlock=new TransformManyBlock<Line,Result>(
                               y=>GetTasksAsync(y.LineCode),
                               options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop):

```
Parallel.ForEach(Lines, (line) =>
{
    globalQueue.AddRange(GetTasks(line.LineCode).ToList());
});
```

> A `Parallel.ForEach` loop works like a `Parallel.For` loop. The loop
> partitions the source collection and schedules the work on multiple
> threads based on the system environment. The more processors on the
> system, the faster the parallel method runs.

Comment: One thing to note here: if globalQueue is not a collection from the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, you might run into thread issues when calling `AddRange()`. I recommend using `ConcurrentBag<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or adding a `lock` before trying to `AddRange()` so that only thread at a time is adding to the Collection.

Comment: If you add a `lock` @Michael then it's no longer parrallel

Comment: @Liam if you add a lock on just the insert (so you extract GetTasks to its own line) then the long running portion will still be paralleled.

Comment: Good that you both have discussed this. I agree it might be necessary to lock the inserting part and without locking the execution of GetTasks method.

Comment: All this is very interesting for me. Thank you.

Comment: @BastienVandamme modifying global state from `Parallel.ForEach` is *not* a good idea. How many lines are there, what does `GetTasks` do? You could use PLINQ for example to perform the entire operation in parallel *without* requiring locks or concurrent queues. Or you could use a different construct to execute IO bound tasks concurrently

Comment: GetTasks call an API that return a list from many table and calculation from several database. What is PLINQ? You are right I should save my results from GetTasks in several list and merge them after the loop, not during the loop.

Comment: @BastienVandamme You *can't* accelerate database access by running multiple queries concurrently. You'll actually cause big delays as the queries conflict with each other, try to use the *same* CPUs, disks and network. You can't fix a slow query by running more slow queries. Please update the question and explain the *actual* problem. Most likely you need to improve the queries. Perhaps you need to add extra indexes.

Comment: Well, this is not the point. Let says that yes, I can accelerate. Do not worry for that.

Comment: No you can't. Otherwise the query would be faster to begin with. Unless you query different *servers*, in which case you *don't* have a parallelism problem and `Parallel` or `PLINQ` won't help *at all*. They'll simply freeze your machine for 1 minute, waiting for responses. *Please* update the question and explain what you want to do

Comment: Yes I can. Trust me. :-) I think I'm simplifying the question too much. Whatever this is not the question. Let says then I really want to test. I want to try.

Comment: @BastienVandamme not like this. You have *only* 8 lines. Have you tried pulling data from 2000 servers concurrently? You don't do that with `Parallel`. And if you *do* use Parallel, I repeat, it uses all cores so it will *freeze* the app waiting for responses. Don't you want to process the results as they arrive?

Comment: No, I need to process the results when I'm sure all arrived.

Comment: @BastienVandamme you need to update the question if you want an answer, explaining the *actual* problem